# How get status back from MPI spawn process?

Tags: ipc, mpi

In an MPI program, using MPI_COMM_SPAWN, one can spawn an mpi process or nonMpi process to other hosts. These children processes spawned will have artifacts to return to the parent upon completion.

For Mpi Processes, I assume one can simply use inter comm to send status, yet, how about the non mpi processes ? I assume I can use tradictional linux IPC to communicate back, which sounds kind of like a hack... Anyone has some brilliant idea about what to do here ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Imho, the only reason to use mpi_comm_spawn is to create new MPI workers dinamically when you can't determine the size before it starts, so there is no meaning to spawn a non-mpi application using mpi_comm_spawn...

Update: According to http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report.pdf, chapter 10, "MPI_COMM_SPAWN in the parents and MPI_INIT in the children form a collective operation over the union of parent and child processes", so it looks like you can not spawn a non-mpi process.